# Results file only printing one line using Perl

Tags: perl, csv, while-loop

I have the following Perl,

```
open (FILE, 'file.htm');
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(do { local $/; <FILE> }); 

for ( $tree->look_down( 'class' => 'postbody' ) )
{     
    my $location = $_->look_down( 'class' => 'posthilit' )->as_trimmed_text;     
    my $comment  = $_->look_down( 'class' => 'content' )->as_trimmed_text;     
    my $name     = $_->look_down( '_tag'  => 'h3' )->as_text;     

    $name =~ s/^Re:\s*//;     $name =~ s/\s*$location\s*$//;      
    print "Name: $name\nLives in: $location\nCommented: $comment\n";

    my $csv = Text::CSV->new(); 
    $csv->column_names('field1', 'field2', 'field3'); 
    $csv->print ($fh, [$name,$location,$comment]);
    open $fh, ">", "file.csv" or die "ERROR: $!";
    close $fh or die "$!";
}
```

This only outputs one line from the input file into the new 'file.csv' file.
How can I get it to put all the results into the results file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where `$name`, `$location` and `$comment` come from ?

Comment: I have added in the rest of the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as written only prints one line because you only call `$csv->print` once. Since you obviously have more than one line of data, you need to create a loop that prints all of the lines. Something like this:

```
while (my ($name, $location, $comment) = next_record()) {
    $csv->print($fh, [$name, $location, $comment]);
}
```

I can't give you any more detailed answer than this without seeing the rest of your code and knowing how the variables `$name, $location, $comment` are assigned.

---

**Update** after the question was edited:

You have a loop with `for ($tree->look_down(...))`, which is fine and takes the place of the `while` loop that I described above. However, as currently written, you're making a new `$csv` object and a new file every time through the loop! That's why you only every get one line in the output file. You need to take the following lines and put them *before* the beginning of the `for` loop:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new(); 
$csv->column_names('field1', 'field2', 'field3');
open $fh, ">", "file.csv" or die "ERROR: $!";
```

*Inside* the loop you only need to do this:

```
$csv->print ($fh, [$name,$location,$comment]);
```

Then once the loop has completed, you can do this:

```
close $fh or die "$!";
```

Comment: thats good, it doesnt seem to like the next_record part however? Brings up an undefined subroutine error...

Comment: @Jambo, that's because `next_record` is just something that I made up to illustrate how you could write the loop. *You* are the one that understands where your data is coming from, and *you're* the one who knows how to iterate all of your records to write them to the file.

Comment: I see, I have added in the rst of the script, with the loop you stated, however still unsure what to put in the new_record part?

Comment: Fantastic! It is now importing all the data, great code @JSBANGS, only problem is the data isn't going into columns but one massive row, and the headers 'field1' etc are not present, can you think of any reason for this?

Comment: @Jambo, you can probably work out the reasons for that by looking at the documentation for Text::CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Use eol => "\n" like...

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } )
    or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just check the documentation of [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm)
You should open the file for reading and there is a ***getline*** method.

Comment: Irrelevant. He wants to know how to *write* data, not *read* it.

Comment: Yep my mistake, seems like I misunderstood the question.